# Cypress test with selectric

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I am using Cypress test to test my project and which I wrote with the help of jquery
I used selectric library for my select, and I came across one problem which is I cannot test my select.
Please help me with this situation.
I have written my code and error which cypress gives in below

```
<select name="prefix" id="prefix_id" class="select-area">
            <option value="1">all</option>
            <option value="1">200 xxxx</option>
            <option value="2">255 xxxx</option>
</select>
```

```
it('search number', () => {
   cy.get('#prefix_id').select('1');
});
```

CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.select() failed because this element:

```
<select class="select-area" name="region-select" id="region_id" tabindex="-1">...</select>
```

is being covered by another element:

```
<div class="selectric">...</div>
```

Fix this problem, or use {force: true} to disable error checking.

https://on.cypress.io/element-cannot-be-interacted-with

Comment: Did you try `cy.get('#prefix_id').select('1', ( force: true });`, which is the syntax that the error message is suggesting?

Comment: I have solved my problem I will post under this

Comment: Yeah I have done that and it solves the problem but I have ajax request to the back-end and  the select couldn't get the value of the option, therefore, I have solved in that way which I wrote in bellow

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I needed to click to div of

```
<div class="selectric">...</div>
```

after that options will be opened in the list format like

```
<ul>
<li>hey</li>
<li>hey2</li>
</ul>
```

then needed to click to option

```
cy.get('.region-container > .selectric-wrapper').click();
cy.get('.region-container > .selectric-wrapper > .selectric-items > .selectric-scroll > ul > .last').click();
```

My select and label are inside one container which class is region container